# How to deal with errors using all effect in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, es6-promise, redux-saga

I'm using `redux-saga` to start multiple requests concurrently as described in [the redux-saga docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RunningTasksInParallel.html). The `all` effect has an `all or nothing semantics`, similar to `Promise.all`.

Only if all `effects` succeed, `yield all([...])` succeeds. However, I am doing several requests from which I expect some of them to fail and some of them to succeed. I would like to start all of them in parallel and consume the responses from those requests that have succeeded.

Therefore, I tried to wrap the request into a `Promise` that always resolves no matter whether the request was successful or not:

```
// watcher saga
export function* watchMultipleRequests() {
  while(true) {
    const {ids} = yield take('VIDEOS_REQUEST');
    yield fork(doMultipleRequests, ids);
  }
}

// worker saga
export function* doMultipleRequests(ids) {
  const requests = ids.map(id => {
    // api.buildVideoRequest returns a promise once it is invoked
    const wrapper = ignoreErrors(api.buildVideoRequest, id);
    return call(wrapper);
  });
  try {
    const responses = yield all(requests);
    yield put({type: 'VIDEOS_SUCCESS', responses});
  } catch (error) {
    // should not happen because we are always resolving the promise
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export function ignoreErrors(fn, ...args) {
  return function* () {
    yield new Promise(function (resolve) {
      return fn(...args)
        .then(response => {
          console.log('success = ', response);
          resolve(response);
        })
        .catch(response => {
          console.log('error = ', response);
          resolve(response);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

I would like to handle the error cases in the `reducer`. However, if I fire `n` requests, the `responses` array contains `n` times `undefined`. Has anyone a clue on why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the ignoreErros function is a generator function.
Implementing it like this:

```
export function ignoreErrors(fn, ...args) {
  return () => {
    const ignoreErrorCallback = (response) => response;
    return fn(...args).then(ignoreErrorCallback, ignoreErrorCallback);
  };
}
```

is sufficient.